# Getting generated key from DB2 using MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a table that generates with an auto-generated column but I am unable to retrieve the ID using MyBatis. I have proven through tests that the SQL is working and that the rows are being inserted but I cannot get the ID generated.

The XML configuration is:

```
<insert id="insertRequestTrackingRow" parameterType="map">
    INSERT INTO XML_LOG_T (REQ_SRC_SYS_CDE, REQ_USR_ID, REQ_XML_DOC, ROW_CRT_DTM, ROW_UPDT_DTM)
    VALUES (#{sourceSystemCode}, #{userID}, #{message}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
</insert>
```

On the XML_LOG_T is a column, REQ_ID, that is auto-generated. My mapper interface is:

```
public interface UdbDataMapper {
    int insertRequestTrackingRow(
            @Param("message") String message,
            @Param("sourceSystemCode") String sourceSystemCode,
            @Param("userID") String userID);
}
```

What is returned is always 1, which I believe is the number of records inserted. I'm sure I am missing something obvious but cannot see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty good [explanation](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2010/12/beginning-mybatis-3-part-3-how-to-get-tables-generated-ids/) of how to do this.

Basically you have to use the useGeneratedKeys="true" and keyproperty="keyfield" attributes in your XML configuration for the INSERT statement.  The returned key field value is then inserted into your parameter object and can be retrieved from there.  Something like the following code sample should work:

```
SqlSessionFactory sqlMapper = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(Resources.getResourceAsReader("sqlConfig.xml"));
SqlSession sess = sqlMapper.openSession();
try {
   Map<String,String> paramObj = new HashMap<String,String>();
   paramObj.put("param1", "value");
   int result = sess.insert("insertRequestTrackingRow", paramObj);
   System.out.println("REQ_ID: " + paramObj.get("REQ_ID"));
}
finally {
   sess.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have see those attributes in the documentation but they rely on my passing an object into the database, right? I would rather not invent an object just to get data into the DB and the generated key out again but perhaps it is the only way.

Comment: The generated key value will be inserted into whatever parameter object you use, as long as it has a setter that MyBatis can use to set the value.  See edited code in my response above.

Comment: When you said "as long as it has a setter" it all became clear. I actually changed my implementation and am now passing an object around the place, but your answer was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<insert id="insertRequestTrackingRow" parameterType="map" 
        useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
    INSERT INTO XML_LOG_T (REQ_SRC_SYS_CDE, REQ_USR_ID, REQ_XML_DOC, ROW_CRT_DTM, ROW_UPDT_DTM)
    VALUES (#{sourceSystemCode}, #{userID}, #{message}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
</insert>
```